# need to press on the letters in listview and not on the line itself

Tags: android, listview

i have a listview, my problem is that a "click" will register only if i press on the text, and not on the line itself.
how can i change that?

```
public class Listwithbaseadapter extends ListActivity {

static final String[] MOBILE_OS = 
        new String[] { "Android", "iOS", "royi", "Blackberry"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setCacheColorHint(0);

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    //get selected items
    String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the android:layout_width="wrap_content" to android:layout_width="fill_parent" in the xml. Thanks anyway.